# Adding Action Bar and Navigation Drawer together without actionbar sherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have already implemented navigation drawer in my app and I want to add swipe Tabs also in my activity. Is it possible to add both these functions in a single activity ? How ?
I have searched many ways  to make tabs but no success.

I have also tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783823/action-bar-tabs-using-viewpager-with-navigation-drawer) but I don't know how to complete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your onCreate method :

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

And to add tabs :

```
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Title 1").setTabListener(this));
actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Title 2").setTabListener(this));
...
```

And your activity needs to implement `ActionBar.TabListener` which has `onTabSelected` method that is called when the user clicks on another tab. You will then do whatever you like.

To link to tabs to a ViewPager :

When the user swype the viewpager, change the tab indicator.

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
```

and when the user clicks on a tab, select the proper page of the viewpager.

```
@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: NullPointerError on actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: How do you get the action bar ? Because  if you can't even get a reference to the action bar you have a problem.

Comment: hey sorry it worked. I did something wrong. Thanks alot. This is great.

Comment: how do I add view pager on it ?

Comment: Tabs and ViewPager are not linked. Make your ViewPager work and then check the code that I've added.

Comment: I added ViewPager in DrawerLayout. Is it right? Because its not working.

Comment: Yes as the second child of the DrawerLayout. Even without Drawer or Tabs, the ViewPager should allow swyping between the pages, so make  that work first.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

you can use getSupportActionBar() (which is in support library,you can use drawwer layout also)

Comment: I tried using it but when i add tabs app crashes. Can u give me an example.

Comment: Gagan better you post your logcat when app crashes .So that we can help you.Without knowing why app crash it is difficult to handle