# How to add Tabhost in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation-drawer, android-tabhost

In my app I am using navigation drawer from this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Now I am trying to add tabhost with fragment,but its not working

it shows error here tabss.setViewPager(mViewPager);

Cannot resolve method setviewpager(android.support.v4.view.viewpager)

```
public class All_Product_Details extends Fragment {


    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private YourAdapter mTabsAdapter;

    private Button descr;
    private TextView general_desc;
    private TextView short_desc;
    private TextView full_desc;


    private Button btn_add_to_cart;

    public All_Product_Details(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_product_detais, container, false);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mTabsAdapter= new YourAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsAdapter);
        TabWidget tabss = (TabWidget)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabss.setViewPager(mViewPager);


        general_desc=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.general_desc);
        short_desc=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.short_desc);
        full_desc=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.full_desc);

       btn_add_to_cart=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_addtocart);
        btn_add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Add_to_cart tf = new Add_to_cart();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, tf);
                ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });


        short_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        full_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        descr=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.all_prod_description);
        descr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hidebackground);
        descr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (flag == 0) {
                    descr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.showbackground);
                    //lnrallbtns.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    general_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    flag++;
                } else {
                    descr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hidebackground);
                   // lnrallbtns.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    general_desc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    short_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    full_desc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    flag = 0;
                }
            }
        });

      return rootView;
    }

    public class YourAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private String[] titles = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3" };
        public YourAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch(i){
                case 0:{
                    return new FragementA();
                }case 1:{
                    return new FragmentB();
                }case 2:{
                    return new FragmentC();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return titles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return titles[position];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: it shows error here tabss.setViewPager(mViewPager);

Comment: it shows cannot resolve method

Comment: Improve your question, showing what the exception is.

Comment: @DavidePastore can you tell

Comment: I don't know. Wait and see if somebody else has an answer.

Comment: There is no such method `setViewPager()` on a `TabWidget`. Why are you trying to call that method? Did you check the documentation to see if such a method exists?

Comment: i think its not there,,but can you help me to add tab host?

Comment: You SHOULDN'T add a TabHost to a NavView - this is non-standard (again DON'T do this!).

Comment: @Booger in facebook they used i think..and is there any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and referred an awsm example called [Balaji-K13](https://github.com/Balaji-K13/Navigation-drawer-page-sliding-tab-strip) .

You can add whatever your list in here like:

Inside **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.webileapps.navdrawer;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
        mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
        R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
        R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
            com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home: {
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
            break;
        }

        case R.id.action_contact:
            // QuickContactFragment dialog = new QuickContactFragment();
            // dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "QuickContactFragment");
            // return true;

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content,
                            PageSlidingTabStripFragment.newInstance(),
                            PageSlidingTabStripFragment.TAG).commit();
            break;
        default:

            SherlockFragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
            fragment.setArguments(args);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
            break;
        }

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }



}
```

Inside **PageSlidingTabStripFragment.java**

```
    package com.webileapps.navdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;

public class PageSlidingTabStripFragment extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = PageSlidingTabStripFragment.class
            .getSimpleName();

    public static PageSlidingTabStripFragment newInstance() {
        return new PageSlidingTabStripFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        private final String[] TITLES = { "Categories", "Home", "Top Paid",
                "Top Free" };

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
            return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }
    }
```

Inside **PlanetFragment.java**

```
package com.webileapps.navdrawer;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class PlanetFragment extends SherlockFragment {
    public static final String ARG_PLANET_NUMBER = "planet_number";

    public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container,
                false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PLANET_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
                planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
                getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image))
                .setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And finally **SuperAwesomeCardFragment.java**

```
package com.webileapps.navdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class SuperAwesomeCardFragment extends SherlockFragment{

    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

    private int position;

    public static SuperAwesomeCardFragment newInstance(int position) {
        SuperAwesomeCardFragment f = new SuperAwesomeCardFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        f.setArguments(b);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        fl.setLayoutParams(params);

        final int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());

        TextView v = new TextView(getActivity());
        params.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setLayoutParams(params);
        v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_card);
        v.setText("CARD " + (position + 1));

        fl.addView(v);
        return fl;
    }

}
```

Hope this Helped :)

Comment: yes i import that and it works well..thanks for help