# How to put Sidebar and Tabbed Actionbar on the same Activity?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, sidebar

I am new to Android, I don't know if I make myself clear enough.

I want to make an app with a sidebar like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCTxa.png

and when UKT is selected open the corresponding frame with tabs
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPIF9.png

I can do this on separate activities, but I want to still have a sidebar when UKT is clicked.

Is there to do this without actionbarsherlock as suggested here?
[Action Bar Tabs using ViewPager with Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783823/action-bar-tabs-using-viewpager-with-navigation-drawer)

Comment: You should research NavigationView. it's a lot easier that way because you can use OpenDrawers or CloseDrawers and it's a lot cleaner. And you should replace ActionBar With Toolbar.

Comment: @Renges I will look it up. Thanks.